# Does hibernate listener async?

Tags: java, hibernate, listener

Hibernate has [listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e1578) are they synchronous or not? E.g. when I subsribed to `save` action, can I perform some havy logic?

Comment: You could check it yourself by printing out the current thread id, one in the Hibernate logger and the other one is in the place you call the Session.save method.

Comment: "Heavy logic", synchronous, asynchronous are completely different things. Altering entity relationships in entity listeners is not recommended for portable applications (by the JPA spec). The order in which entity listeners are invoked while cascading is undefined. Thus, applications relying upon the specific order in which entity listeners are invoked is forbidden by the JPA spec. Portable applications should thus not rely upon the specific order in which entity listeners are invoked.

Comment: Well, heavy logic could be calling some external service or performing some cpu intensive task. In that sense, I also can't understand if it would be OK to put something inside. Also it matters if it is synchronous or not - if the callback has to complete before the control is turned over to the code that did the persisting/deleting/whatever then that could be a big no-no

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Section : [JPA Callbacks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks)

UPDATE 2: Added current link

UPDATE: Link is dead but the screenshot reflects the essential content

Hope this helps

Comment: Link is now dead

Comment: That's why I've attached the screenshot as well.